# Prolog same predicate with different elements?

Tags: prolog

The idea is that I have some rooms in a hotel to associate with guests.

```
guest(FamilySurname,RoomTaken) or guest(FamilySurname, [RoomsTaken])
```

So I can have two ways to write the same predicate, the first using a single element in RoomTaken, the second one using a list.
I want to know if a generic room X is free or not, so I have written the following code:

```
iterativefree(X,[]).
iterativefree(X,Y) :- Y=[H|T] , H \= X , iterativefree(X,T).
free(X) :- forall(guest(_,Y) , ( Y \= [_,_] , X \= Y) ) .             
free(X) :- forall(guest(_,Y) , (Y=[H|T] , H \= X) ) , iterativefree(X,T).
```

I have thought to use an OR to let my program be able to work in both cases, so the third row works in the first case (RoomTaken is a single element), the fourth in the second case (RoomTaken is a list), but something doesn't work, and I'm really not able to understand what because trace doesn't give me any information... it just calls the predicate and give me the answer.

```
trace , guest(ciao, [room8 , room1] ), free(room7).

 Call:guest(ciao, [room8, room1])
false
```

Could someone let me understand where I'm failing? Thanks.

**EDIT:**
As someone has suggested in the comments I have defined my guest predicate in the program and not in the query so trace is now working properly, but I have noticed that there is a problem in the Y=[H|T]

```
guest(ciao,[room8,room1]).
iterativefree(_,[]).
iterativefree(X,Y) :- Y=[H|T] , H \= X , iterativefree(X,T).
free(X) :-  forall(guest(_,Y) , (Y \= [_|_] , Y \= X) ).
free(X) :-   forall(guest(_,Y) , (Y=[H|T] , H \= X) ) , iterativefree(X,T).
```

---

```
trace , free(room5)
 Call:free(room5)
 Call:guest(_16142, _16144)
 Exit:guest(amo, [room1, room17, room5])
 Call:[room1, room17, room5]\=[_16056|_16058]
 Fail:[room1, room17, room5]\=[_16056|_16058]
 Redo:free(room5)
 Call:guest(_16142, _16144)
 Exit:guest(amo, [room1, room17, room5])
 **Call:[room1, room17, room5]=[_16056|_16058]**
 Exit:[room1, room17, room5]=[room1, room17, room5]
 Call:room1\=room5
 Exit:room1\=room5
 Call:iterativefree(room5, _16144)
 Exit:iterativefree(room5, [])
 Exit:free(room5)
true
```

So it seems that in the highlighted call the program isn't associating [room17,room5] to T. Why is this happening? Thanks.

Comment: The error seems to came from the fact that guest(ciao,[room8,room1]) is not defined in the program

Comment: I don't see a definition for `guest`.